# How could I download a file like .csv or .h5 from Google colab to local hard drive?

Tags: python, pandas, google-colaboratory

**Here is a sample code:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,1), columns=['x1'])
```

To download this df in .csv format I used the following codes:

```
> codes

from google.colab import files

with open('df.csv', 'w') as f:

  f.write('df')

files.download('df.csv')
```

> Output

But instead of getting the intended file on my hard drive I got df.csv file containing a text 'df'.

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` or `deep-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: If you want a csv file, then try python CSV module. Second what i can see in your code is you have only written 'df' in your file and nothing else.

Comment: Thanks. I got it. I should have used data.csv_to().

Comment: Can you explain with more details what do you want to do, because  I can't understand  what do you really need, and I couldn't find a logic to your code